# create table tab ( id numeric(6) primary key, class numeric(3), fdate date, group char(6), foreign key (class, fdate) references exam(class, fdate));

Tags: sql

#1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MariaDB на предмет корректного синтаксиса около 'group char(6), foreign key (class, fdate) references exam(class, fdate))' на строке 1

Answer (score 0):

`group` - служебное слово, оберните его в символы `:

```
create table tab (
id numeric(6) primary key,
class numeric(3),
fdate date,
`group` char(6),
CONSTRAINT `fk_tab_ref_exam` foreign key (class, fdate) references exam(class, fdate)
);
```

Comment: В MariaDB - не кавычки, а бэктики.

Comment: Точняк, перепутал с PostgreSQL.

Comment: (ошибка: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Comment: Не хватает `CONSTRAINT имя_форин_кея` перед foreign key. "имя_форин_кея" также обернуть в бэктики

Comment: @Ева *ошибка: 150* Сверьте типы данных колонок внешнего ключа в таблицах - должны совпадать, что называется, до запятых. Если с этой стороны всё в порядке - значит. в таблицах уже имеются данные, для которых соответствие внешнего ключа не выполняется, проверяйте и корректируйте данные.

Comment: *Не хватает `CONSTRAINT имя_форин_кея` перед foreign key.* Не требуется - MySQL сформирует предложение автоматически, если оно опущено.